# Restify: Calling a middleware within a middleware

Tags: node.js, express, restify

I have a middleware for authentication which decrypts the token in the header and put the `userId` from the token to `req.userId`. Otherwise it throws an error if token doesn't exists or is invalid.

I call it like this in routes where I need authentication:

```
server.get('/api/somecall', authMiddleware, callService.somecall);
```

Now I will also have some routes which will carry a user ID in its params, like this:

```
server.get('/api/somecall/:userId', callService.somecall);
```

Here `:userId` can be a Mongoose Object ID or just `me`.

So I want to write another middleware which will be called for all routes that looks for particular `params` like `userId` and/or `adminId`. And if their value equals `me`, I want to make sure that `authMiddleware` automatically comes to action, PLUS replace `me` with the logged in user's ID so the `callService.somecall` handles the logic inside as it received a Mongoose Object ID.

There are two problems I'm facing:

- How do I get `req.params.userId` in a middleware which is called before `server.get(...)`?
- Suppose if I get `req.params.userId` somehow, how do I make the middleware to:

  - perform some condition (check if `req.params.userId === 'me'`),
  - then call `authMiddleware` so that I get `req.userId` from token, and
  - then perform more actions (replace `req.params.userId = req.userId`
  - then call `next()` to continue.

Answer (score -1):

Your question is a little confusing so I don't know if this will help, but why not do something like this:

```
server.get('/api/somecall/:userId', otherMiddleware, callService.somecall);

function otherMiddleware(req, res, next){
    if(req.params.userId === 'me'){
        authMiddleware(req, res, next);
    }

    // Do other stuff here.

    next();
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I actually modified the `authMiddleware` and did the `params` thing inside it.

Comment: This will cause error: `next shouldn't be called more than once`. Assuming `authMiddleware` is written correctly, it would have already called `next()` already and the one in `otherMiddleware` will cause error